# how can I access my facebook page's insights?

Tags: facebook

Do I need to sign up somewhere to access my page's insights? According to https://www.facebook.com/help/383440231709427/ it should just show up on the top of the page, but I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the following URL and select your page:

https://www.facebook.com/insights

You can also use a direct URL by appending `/insights/` to your page's URL:

https://www.facebook.com/YOURPAGE/insights/

Comment: I got "Sorry, this content isn't available right now" error when I tried your suggestions.

Comment: That means you don't have sufficient rights to view the insights OR that there's not enough data for the insights to show up.